# Find All Radio Buttons in ASP Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, foreach, controls

I have an ASP table which contains a large number of radio buttons.  I want to loop through them all quickly and set the checked property to false:

```
   <asp:Table runat=Server ID=tblSchedule>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:RadioButton runat=Server ID=rdb1/>
</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
</asp:table>
```

The following code never returns any results though.

```
foreach (RadioButton rdb in tblSchedule.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
{
    rdb.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: A table without rows? Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx) how you use the table control or use a `Panel` or a databound webcontrol like `Repeater` instead.

Comment: Sorry I just trimmed up too much for the post, I put back in more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the layers of the table control, like this:

```
foreach (var tr in tblSchedule.Controls.OfType<TableRow>())
{
    foreach (var td in tr.Controls.OfType<TableCell>())
    {
        foreach (var rdb in td.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
        {
            rdb.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Or alternatively you can use LINQ, like this:

```
foreach (var rdb in tblSchedule.Controls.OfType<TableRow>()
    .SelectMany(tr => tr.Controls.OfType<TableCell>()
    .SelectMany(td => td.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())))
{
    rdb.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: The Linq version was very easy to implement, I'm not quite sure I understand .SelectMany (tr => tr.Controls

Comment: @JStellato - The `SelectMany()` is meant to flatten data down to one collection of data. For example, say you had a stack of books on your desk and you wanted to create a list of all of the authors of all the books in the stack. As a human, you would get a sheet of paper and start with the first book, write down the author or authors of the book in a single list on the sheet of paper; this is effectively what `SelectMany()` does in LINQ.

Comment: @JStellato - If you were to just use a `Select()`, then you would get a single list of authors for each book and then have to compile the list together; think a separate sheet of paper for each book. Now with x sheets of paper, you would need to go through each sheet to build a master list to end up with a single list. So instead of building a list of lists, `SelectMany()` gets us straight to the desired single list of data output.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember the table's control cllection does not contain all controls in all rows' cells. `Controls.OfType` does not search recursively in child controls. So you either have to use a recursive method or just use the `Rows` property and this linq query:

```
IEnumerale<RadioButton> allRadios = this.tblSchedule.Rows.Cast<TableRow>()
     .SelectMany(r => r.Cells.Cast<TableCell>()
                       .SelectMany(c => c.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()));

foreach(RadioButton rBtn in allRadios)
    rBtn.Checked = false;
```